# How to search only some specific sites using result source - SharePoint Online

Tags: sharepoint-server, search-results, content-search-web-part, sharepoint-search, kql-query

I have couple of sites and subsites and would like to create a result source just for these sites. Then my intention is to add a new search webpart or use the existing one but change it to use my new result source.
under Query Transform > when i click on Launch Query Builder >
What do i need to do to add the multiple site url like so

```
Path={Site.URL} e.g http://Catalog,http://news,http:blog etc..
```

Also is it possible to remove some properties i don't want it to return e.g modified/created by or some default pages

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set your `Query Transform` to

> {searchTerms} (Path:http://Catalog OR Path:http://news OR
>   Path:http://blog)

As for removing properties, you can customize search results display template but KQL will return all specified searchable columns.

Answer (score 2):

To remove some properties, exclude a Column from SharePoint Search Crawl for your reference:

https://www.sharepointdiary.com/2014/02/exclude-column-from-sharepoint-search-crawl.html

Comment: Thanks for the tip to exclude a column/s.Any ideas what i would need to be able to remove some specific urls? e.g for the blog site i would like to exclude allposts.aspx

Comment: Similar issue post for your reference: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/f233caee-6bb0-470d-a763-4eaee5d63732/exclude-allitemsaspx-from-search-in-sharepoint-online?forum=sharepointdevelopment

Comment: Thanks Lisa will check it out

Comment: Thanks Lisa..I modified my result source to e.g {?{searchTerms} -Filename:https://abc/sites/xxx/yyy/Pages/Forms/AllItems.aspx} but it didn't work when i tested it out