# How do you specify a site in a KQL SharePoint search

Tags: sharepoint-online, search, site, kql

In SharePoint Online I sometimes want to perform searches across multiple sites in our work's SP farm. I can search across all sites, but that often gives too many responses. I want to restrict the search to a small number of sites that I mention by name, something like:
`target1 target 2 target 3 sitename:name1 or sitename:site2 or sitename:site3)`
But I keep on getting null results when I know there are files to find. The result messages don't tell me whether I've got wrong the site name or the word I use before the colon ('sitename' in the above).

Can anybody please tell me if there is a sharepoint standard noun to use before the colon to point at site name metadata?

For target site names I used the part `O365-UG-nnnnnn` from the URL of each site, where nnnnnn is a 6-digit number that I presume uniquely identifies the site. See below:

`https://<domain_name>.sharepoint.com/sites/O365-UG-nnnnnn/Shared%20Documents/Forms/AllItems.aspx`

That worked at a place I worked previously (although I can't remember what I wrote before the colon) but it doesn't work at the place I work now, either because I'm using the wrong noun before the colon, or the wrong target after the colon.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

please test with the query below, it works in my end.

```
{searchTerms} (Path:http://site1 OR Path:http://site2 OR Path:http://site3)
```

It has been answered before:[How to search only some specific sites using result source - SharePoint Online](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/271968/how-to-search-only-some-specific-sites-using-result-source-sharepoint-online)

Comment: Thank you. That works on my installation. I had to type in the full URL up to the end of the  site identifier.